# remove contact Cordova 2.5 for IOS not working

Tags: ios, cordova, contacts

I want to ask about remove function from Contact API Cordova 2.5.0. I use xcode 4.6 and Iphone version 5.1.1. Is this really working? Why remove function always go to onRemoveError?

This is the code :

```
       var myContact = navigator.contacts.create();
        myContact.note = document.getElementById('txtNote').value;

        myContact.nickname = document.getElementById('txtNickname').value;      
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = document.getElementById('txtGiven').value;
        name.familyName = document.getElementById('txtFamily').value;
        myContact.name = name;

        // save
        myContact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);

        // remove
        myContact.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
```

Comment: And saving the contact is working?

Answer (score 1):

If your code really looks like that, and you remove *right after* saving, then the save will not have happened yet (as it's handled asynchronously).

You could put the line to remove the contact inside of the "onSaveSuccess" handler, which would make sure that it's called after the contact is actually created.

Comment: i have try your suggestion :


 function onSaveSuccess(contact) 
  {
     alert("Save Success");
     myContact.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
            }
function onRemoveSuccess(contacts) {
                alert("Removal Success");
            }
            
function onRemoveError(contactError) {
                alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
            }'


but only alert can appear, and remove function is nothing happen.

Comment: Which alert was that? Was onRemoveSuccess called? or just the alert("Save Success") ?

Comment: only alert("Save Success")

Comment: That's very strange. A few possibilities I see: 1) there's some kind of alert-suppressing going on -- the browser won't let multiple alerts follow each other. 2) something's been cached so you aren't seeing up-to-date code. Do you have some method other than alerts for logging?

Comment: function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
                alert("Save Success");
                alert("Success");
                myContact.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
            }  


Multiple alerts can appear. I think the problem is the function in CordovaLib

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not on a mac and so can't try out your code myself. But I would be surprised if there was a bug that big. Have you tried removing some other contact that you didn't just create?

Comment: yeah, i ever try that, but still not working. I have follow the instruction in http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts.

Comment: hmm and you have all the permissions? [to viewers: I would move this to chat, but user2146748 doesn't have enough rep yet]